# gen server synchronous and asynchronous calls

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server

Suppose I have a gen_server that is handling only asynch calls (thus only handle_cast is implemented), should i keep handle_call and make it return only the generic ok value, or should i remove that part of the code and accept the warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd opt for always returning `{reply, ok, State}`. Treat warnings as errors (that is, stop compilation and fix them). That way, when real warnings appear, they aren't hidden behind the noise.

It's a good habit to wrap all calls to behaviors in your own function, e.g:

```
delete(Something) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {delete, Something}).
```

In this case, don't export any function which uses `handle_call/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't handling all of the calls a requirement for gen_server, regardless of whether you use them or not?

Comment: I know, i'm asking 'cause i friend asked me about the safety of returning "ok" even though no actions are performed by the server...

Comment: yes, just returning {reply, ok, State} is perfectly acceptable, and normal for ignoring an action.